# Как узнать откуда берется метод Stub() в открытом проекте?

Tags: android, idl

Есть вот такой открытый проект на гугл-коде [тут](https://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/OpenGPSTracker/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/logger/GPSLoggerService.java?name=release_1.3.5) Не могу понять откуда берется метод `.Stub()` в 369 строчке, у меня в Андроид студио он горит красным и написано  Cannot resolve symbol 'Stab'. Что это за метод Stub()?

Компиляция проблему не решает, выдает ошибку

```
C:\...\gpstracker\logger\GPSLoggerService.java
Error:(336, 58) error: cannot find symbol class Stub
Note: C:\...\gpstracker\logger\GPSLoggerService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 7.315 secs
Information:2 errors
```

Comment: А собирается проект нормально? Если да, то значит просто студия подглючивает, такое бывает, ребилд обычно помогает.

Answer (score 1):

`IGPSLoggerServiceRemote` - это удаленный AIDL-интерфейс, который служит для организации связи (передачи параметров) между клиентом и сервисом - интерфейс, написанный на специальном языке, созданном как раз для таких случаев - **A**ndroid **I**nterface **D**efinition **L**anguage (Язык Описания Интерфейсов Android).

Для того ,чтобы интерфейс, написанный на языке AIDL мог существовать в программе, он должен быть преобразован в Java-код. Данный процесс происходит при сборке проекта с помощью утилит, входящих в Android SDK.

`Stub` - это вложенный в реализацию AIDL-интерфейса в Java-коде абстрактный класс (а не метод), который автоматически создается при сборке проекта (при конвертации из AIDL-языка в Java-файл интерфейса). Через этот класс осуществляется получение имплементации AIDL-интерфейса непосредственно на стороне клиента в виде Java-объекта. Так же, через этот класс должны получить конкретную реализацию все методы, задекларированные в AIDL-интерфейсе.
Фактически, через вложенный класс `Stub` создается полноценная Java-реализация интерфейса, описанного на языке AIDL.

[Офф.документация по AIDL](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: Попробовал скомпилировать проект, но он не компилируется выдает ошибки компиляции, лог ошибок показал выше. Это получается API устарело?